# Raid with faulty spare reference but with all physical devices good

Tags: filesystems, mdadm, software-raid

I'm seeing `sdt[6](F)` but I cant remove or set it as failed device

```
# mdadm /dev/md126 --fail /dev/sdt --remove /dev/sdt
mdadm: cannot find /dev/sdt: No such file or directory
```

`/dev/sdt` does not exist anymore as a device

```
# mdadm --detail --scan /dev/md126 
/dev/md126:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 18 11:36:45 2016
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 26371215360 (25149.55 GiB 27004.12 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930135040 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
   Raid Devices : 11
  Total Devices : 12
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Nov  5 07:26:48 2018
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 11
Working Devices : 11
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : diesel-str1:2  (local to host diesel-str1)
           UUID : 1c3c85fa:d93f81cd:4caae0a8:8008a2f5
         Events : 49481

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8      208        0      active sync   /dev/sdn
       1       8      224        1      active sync   /dev/sdo
       2       8      240        2      active sync   /dev/sdp
       3      65        0        3      active sync   /dev/sdq
       4      65       16        4      active sync   /dev/sdr
       5      65       32        5      active sync   /dev/sds
      11      66      112        6      active sync   /dev/sdan
       7      65       64        7      active sync   /dev/sdu
       8      65       80        8      active sync   /dev/sdv
       9      65       96        9      active sync   /dev/sdw
      10      65      112       10      active sync   /dev/sdx

       6      65       48        -      faulty spare
```

and

```
# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid0 md127[0] md124[3] md125[2] md126[1]
      105484859392 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

md124 : active raid6 sde[13] sdam[12] sdaq[11] sdas[9] sdat[10] sdak[1] sdar[8] sdal[2] sdap[6] sdao[5] sdaj[0]
      26371215360 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [11/11] [UUUUUUUUUUU]

md125 : active raid6 sdy[0] sdab[3] sdah[9] sdad[5] sdaf[7] sdag[8] sdai[10] sdac[4] sdae[6] sdaa[2] sdz[1]
      26371215360 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [11/11] [UUUUUUUUUUU]

md126 : active raid6 sdan[11] sdx[10] sdo[1] sdp[2] sdq[3] sds[5] sdn[0] sdw[9] sdu[7] sdr[4] sdv[8] sdt[6](F)
      26371215360 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [11/11] [UUUUUUUUUUU]

md127 : active raid6 sdau[12] sdi[11] sdf[3] sdg[4] sdd[1] sdl[9] sdk[8] sdm[10] sdj[7] sdc[0] sdh[5]
      26371215360 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [11/11] [UUUUUUUUUUU]

md0 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      117215680 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

Comment: did you try `--remove failed` or `--remove detached`?

Comment: `mdadm --remove /dev/md126 detached --test` did the trick thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note from the comments:

```
mdadm -r /dev/md0 detached   # remove failed ones that aren't in /dev anymore
```